# Best way to pass case insensitive parameters

Tags: c#

I have parameters of type string that gets passed to a method. However when the parameter value gets checked in the database , it gets checked for exact case. I need the value to be returned if the value is passed either as "Test" or "TEST" etc.

Currently the values are stored in db as lowercase so I am specifically passing the parameter value with .ToLower

```
Value = Parameter.Uid.ToLower()
```

I was wondering if there is a more cleaner or better way to achieve this istead of adding .ToLower() to every string parameters

Thanks in advance

Comment: What database?  Unless the database requires specific casing, you can use a case-insensitive collation and not have to worry.

Comment: Our installation of SQL Server is case-insensitive by default... not sure about other ORDBMSs..

Comment: We are not able to alter it at the database level, I would prefer doing it in code. Is there a better way then?

Answer (score 2):

An option is to do it in the database query and use a SQL `UPPER(...)` or `LOWER(...)` (where UPPER is more common I'd say).

There are also database collations (look for `_CI`) which are case insensitive.